# Getting JS object values from html input

Tags: javascript, html

So basically my issue is that I'm looking to get some data from an object. The object is picked from and html  tag and the selected option is put into a function. The function handles getting the data but throws an error when trying to get the length of an array found inside the object. getRandInRange is a function I created that works perfectly so that is not the issue.

When I run the code in the browser this is the error I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at buildHorde (app.js:46:60)
    at setValue (app.js:33:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:27:101)
```

```
function buildHorde(obj,num){
    // for every num add a random coin roll
    for (i = 0; i < num; i ++){
        coinArr.push(obj.coins[getRandInRange(0, obj.coins.length-1)]);
    }
    // following lines add the new arrays into the html document.
    document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = coinArr;
    return;
}
```

```
<p>Select Party Level: <select name="Party Level" id="getObj">
    <option value=level1>level1</option>
    <option value=level2>level2</option>
</select></p>
```

And this is the code to set the arguments in the function

```
function setValue(){
    var select = document.getElementById('getObj');
    obj = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value
    num = document.getElementById('getNum').value;
    buildHorde(obj,num);
}
```

level1 object

```
let level1 = {
    coins: ["No coin", getRandInRange(1,6) * 1000 + " Copper Pieces ", getRandInRange(1,8) * 100 + " Silver Pieces ", getRandInRange(1,4) * 10 + " Platinum Pieces "],
    goods: ["nothing ", "Extravagant painting ", "ornate statue "],
    items: ["Boots of speed ", mundane.weapon[getRandInRange(0, mundane.weapon.length-1)], "Potion of fire breathing "],
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you be more specific on what part of the code is not working and what the error message is?

Comment: @nfv Yeah I've gone ahead and done that now.

Comment: It seems to me like `obj.coins` is not defined, or at least is not an array. What is returned from `select.options[select.selectedIndex].value`?

Comment: @nfv The return is level1 which is what I want it to be and yes coins is defined inside of the object level1 and is an array.

Comment: `obj` is a string (as are pretty much all values you get from DOM objects' `value` properties). If you want `obj` to refer to a `level1` variable, there are other ways of doing that.

Comment: no @HereticMonkey that doesn't seem to be it... thanks anyway

Comment: Post what `obj` is supposed to look like because as the code is now `obj = "Level1"` (or `"Level2"`) is what nfv and HM is trying to tell you. You are expecting something like this: `obj = {coins: [1,5,9,1,0,]}` but the `select#getObj` is giving literally a string that is `"Level1"`.

Comment: @zer00ne I have added the level1 object into the post

Comment: @BaileyLong you don't have gold pieces? 

Comment: @zer00ne no I forgot to add them in, I threw the array together very quickly

Comment: @zer00ne so to fix this I would need to get the absolute value back from the form rather than a string correct?

Comment: This question's problem boils down to "How do I access a variable by its name dynamically?", which is not the same as the linked question. Though this question's problem did only arise from a misunderstanding between strings and variables of similar name, as _HereticMonkey_ and _zer00ne_ have pointed out.